# How to Let Java regex Matcher matches the delimeter

Tags: java, regex

Given an error message like "5 : Invalid number : 123***345"

I want to split the message into `error_code` and `error_text`. And in this case, I want to have `5` and `Invalid number : 123***345`.

However, this code splits the matcher into 
`5 : Invalid number` and `123***345`

Which means the regex matches the last `:`.

```
Pattern PROCESSOR_ERROR_INFO_PATTERN_ONE = Pattern.compile("(.*):(.*)");

Matcher matcherOne = PROCESSOR_ERROR_INFO_PATTERN_ONE.matcher(error_message);

if (matcherOne.matches()) {
      processorErrorCode = matcherOne.group(1).trim();
      processorErrorMessage = matcherOne.group(2).trim();
}
```

By the way, there's no guarantee that the error_code is digits only. So I can't use regex like `(\\d+):(.*)`
Is there a way I can control to match the first `:` instead of the default last `:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the first `*` quantifier *lazy* by adding a `?`, so the first group will be as small as possible:

```
Pattern.compile("(.*?):(.*)")
```

Comment: Good answer. On the side note, Oracle tutorials refer to it as reluctant quantifier: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html

Answer (score 2):

Well you could just use [`split(String, int)`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) with a limit of 2. That would be most easy. If you however want to stick to your solution, you can match the first `:` instead of the last `:` by either changing the greedyness of your quantifier (`.*?`) or match everything but `:` (like `([^:]*):(.*)`).